# Angular 1.5 component not seeming to register

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, components, angularjs-components

I am currently writing an app using Angular 1.5's `.component()` method. My component code is as follows:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  function controllerFn($state) {

    console.log('controllerFn'); // this logs fine
    this.testVar = 'test me';

    this.onLoadComplete = function () {
      $state.go('main');
      console.log('load completed')
    };

  }

  APP.component('appPreloader', {
    controller: controllerFn,
    controllerAs: 'appPreloader'
  });

}());
```

and my template code is as follows:

```
<app-preloader class="page-preloader">
      {{appPreloader.testVar}}
      <preloader on-complete="appPreloader.onLoadComplete"></preloader>
</app-preloader>
```

The issue I am having is that `appPreloader` in my view is empty, and for example, `{{appPreloader.testVar}}` renders nothing.

I know this is related to `.components()`'s isolate scope, but I am pretty stumped as to how I should be setting this up for everything to work as should.

Any advice much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have `template`/`templateUrl` with `component`/`directive`, the content which resides inside `directive`/`component` that part of DOM would not compiled with component context. You should have that inner HTML in your `component` inside component `template` so that it would get compiled with component context.

Checkout [**Plunkr Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/vAR1dLwPcrlUeZMCeqq1?p=preview), here you can see inside `app-preloader` you can access the variables(context) of `mainCtrl`.

Whereas if you can check [**this plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wJvB2UcDnVO2u3YvNljy?p=preview) I just moved the inner html of component directly to the component `template` property which started working.

Comment: Thanks very much. Bit of an oversight on my behalf. So am I right in saying that this is something that differs to `.directive()` as `.directive()` does not always require a template or templateUrl?